# Join each argument with the positional number of the argument using null byte as a separator?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to join each argument with the positional number of the argument. I want to use only null bytes as the separator.
The following does what i want:

```
f() {
   for ((i=1;i<$(($#+1));++i)); do
     echo -n "$i"
     echo -ne "\x00"
     echo -n "${!i}"
     echo -ne "\x00"
   done
}

f a b c | hexdump -C
00000000  31 00 61 00 32 00 62 00  33 00 63 00              |1.a.2.b.3.c.|
0000000c
```

However I want to remove the for loop (cause it's ugly) and use pipes and/or process substitutions. So the question is really: how to join two null byte separated streams using null byte as the separator.
I tried using paste:

```
printf '%s\x00' "$@" | paste -z -d '\0' <(seq $# | tr '\n' '\0') -
```

But when invoking paste with `-d'\0'` paste will insert no delimeter at all. Without specifying the delimeter, paste uses tab. Is there a way I can make paste use null byte as a column delimeter? Is there another utility which will work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness, a non-looping construct using only printf (but using it twice):

```
printf "$(printf '%d\\000%%s\\000' $(seq $#))" "$@"
```

The inner `printf` creates a format string prepopulated with sequence numbers. `\000` is necessary to prevent digits at the start of the interpolated strings being incorporated into the escape code.

Comment: I choose this one. It doesn't have any loops and it can deal with all 0x01 - 0xff characters.

Answer (score 1):

The loop isn't the problem; it's your use of the loop.

```
f () {
  local i
  for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
    printf '%d\0%s\0' "$i" "${!i}"
  done
}
```

or possibly

```
f () {
  i=1
  for arg; do
    printf '%d\0%s\0' "$((i++))" "$arg"
  done
}
```

which will work in any POSIX shell, although it overwrites the global `i`.

Answer (score 1):

[`for` loop answer by Chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50682890/548225) is very simple to use and definitely takes care of ugliness issue.

Just as an alternative here is a way to do to it without loop:

```
paste -zd $'\01' <(seq $# | tr '\n' '\0') <(printf '%s\0' "$@") | tr '\1' '\0'
```

This `paste` command pastes both streams with `\01` as column delimiter and last `tr` command converts `\01` to `\0` (NUL) byte.